# Binding JQuery Tabs Using Knockout JS

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have ViewModel like this:

```
function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.Tab = function (id, name, text, selected) {
            var tab = this;
            tab.id = ko.observable(id);
            tab.name = ko.observable(name);
            tab.text = ko.observable(text);
            return tab;
        };
        self.selectedTab = ko.observable(1);
        self.tabs = new Array();
        self.tabs.push(new self.Tab(1, 'Tab 1', 'Tab 1 Content'));
        self.tabs.push(new self.Tab(2, 'Tab 2', 'Tab 2 Content'));
        self.tabs.push(new self.Tab(3, 'Tab 3', 'Tab 3 Content'));
        self.tabs.push(new self.Tab(4, 'Tab 4', 'Tab 4 Content'));
        return self;
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(), document.getElementById("TabDiv"));
```

And related HTML is as follows:

```
  <div id="TabDiv">
            <div id="tabs" data-bind="foreach: tabs">
                <div class="tab" data-bind="css: {selected: $parent.selectedTab() == id()}, text:     name, click: $parent.selectedTab.bind($parent, id())">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabContent" data-bind="foreach: tabs">
                <div data-bind="if: $parent.selectedTab() == id()">
                    <span data-bind="text: text"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
   </div>
```

Now,i have another ViewModel as Follows:

```
var ProjectViewModel = {
 ........
 AddEmployee: function (data, event) {
     $('.chkList').each(function () {
         //Here i want to generate tab
     });
 }
};
```

The checkbox list is binded to one of the observable array of ProjectViewModel which is all working fine. What i am trying to do is,on click of the checkbox inside checkbox list, generate a Tab(similar to Jquery UI Tab).

You can see 4 tab values inserted statically which is working perfectly. I am getting tab as expected. But i am not able to push values which i get inside ProjectViewModel's AddEmployee function into tabs array in ViewModel. I don't know how to process self.tabs.push(new self.Tab(.....)); outside the ViewModel.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ko.dataFor()` to access the view-model:

```
AddEmployee: function (data, event) {
     var vm = ko.dataFor(document.getElementById("TabDiv"));

     vm.tabs.push(new vm.Tab(5, 'New Tab', 'New Tab Content'));
 }
```

Alternatively, you can expose the view-model to the global scope then access it everywhere:

```
window.tabsVM = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(window.tabsVM, document.getElementById("TabDiv"));
```

Then:

```
AddEmployee: function (data, event) {
     var vm = window.tabsVM;

     vm.tabs.push(new vm.Tab(5, 'New Tab', 'New Tab Content'));
}
```

Also, you'll have to change your `tabs` array into an observable-array if you want your changes to update the DOM automatically:

```
self.tabs = ko.observableArray();
```